# Replace multiple elements at different positions

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have a list `a = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};` and now I would like to make only those elements 100 at the positions in `pu = {1,4,5};`
So I would like to get `{100,0,0,100,100}`
`ReplacePart[a, pu -> 100]`, doesn't show the right result unfortunately.
Could anybody help me to solve this?

Thank you in advance!
Carlijn Bakker

Comment: Try with `Thread[pu -> 100]` or `Transpose[{pu}] -> 100`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use lists with `Part` or `[[ ]]`

```
a = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
a[[{1, 3}]] = 7;
a
pu = {1, 4, 5};
a[[pu]] = 100;
a
```

> {7, 0, 7, 0, 0}
>
> {100, 0, 7, 100, 100}

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution and the quick respons!!

Comment: No worries :D Since you are new, dont forget to accept an answer if it solved your problem, that is useful for every body.

Comment: Okay great! I'll do that, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

**Re: `ReplacePart[a, pu -> 100]`, *doesn't show the right result unfortunately*:**

You can use `List/@pu -> 100` instead of `pu -> 100`

```
a = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; pu = {1, 4, 5};

ReplacePart[a, List /@ pu -> 100]
```

> {100, 0, 0, 100, 100}

You can also use `MapAt`:

```
MapAt[100 &, a, List /@ pu]
```

> {100, 0, 0, 100, 100}

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

p = {1, 4, 5};
```

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
f = ReplaceAt[_ :> 100, List /@ p];

f @ a
```

{100, 0, 0, 100, 100}

With `ApplyTo` (new in 12.2) we can change `a` inline (like in the
accepted answer)

```
a //= f;

a
```

{100, 0, 0, 100, 100}

`ReplaceAt` has the advantage that we can easily impose conditions

```
a = {0, Missing[], 0, 0, 0};

p = {1, 4, 5};

ReplaceAt[_?NumberQ :> 100, List /@ p] @ a
```

{100, Missing[], 0, 100, 100}

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

p = {1, 4, 5};
```

---

Using `SubsetMap`:

```
SubsetMap[100 + # &, a, p]

(*{100, 0, 0, 100, 100}*)
```

Comment: One of my favourite functions cleverly employed :)

Comment: Thanks, @eldo! It's also one of my favorite functions ;)